# Prove that if $|f(z)| \geq |f(z_{0})|$ then $f(z_{0})=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open connected subset and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an holomorphic function.
Let $z_{0} \in U$ and $r > 0$ with $B_{r}(z_{0}) \subseteq U$.
If $\forall z \in B_{r}(z_{0})$  $|f(z)| \geq |f(z_{0})|$ then $f(z_{0})=0$.

As $f$ is an holomorphic map $f$ has the mean value property and then
$|f(z_{0})|\leq \max_{\partial B_{r}(z_{0})}|f|$
but I don't how to derive that is zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have the assumptions exactly right? It does follow that the function is constant or vanishes at the point, but you can't rule either case out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(z_0)\not=0$ consider an open connected nbd $V$ of $z_0$ in which $f$ is never vanishes and then apply maximum modules principal to $g:=\frac{1}{f|_V}$. That's $|g|\leq |g(z_0)|$, so $g$ is constant on $V$. So identity theorem implies $f\equiv f(z_0)$ on $U$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that $f$ is not a constant. Otherwise $f=1$ would give a counter-example. Now assume that $f$ is not a constant.

If $f(z_0)$ is not $0$ the $|\frac 1  f|$ attains its maximum at an ineterior point of $B_r(z_0)$ contradicting Maximum Modulus Principle.